# How to check if view inside a dialog is focused?

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

I have a Alert dialog box  with two **SearchView** Widgets like this:

Layout file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <SearchView
        android:id="@+id/sourceSearchView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:iconifiedByDefault="false" >
    </SearchView>

    <SearchView
        android:id="@+id/destinationSearchView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:iconifiedByDefault="false">
    </SearchView>

</LinearLayout>
```

and in below code I inflated this layout to get dialog:

```
LayoutInflater mInflater = (LayoutInflater)mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                View mView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.search_layout,null);

                mSourceSearchView = (SearchView)mView.findViewById(R.id.sourceSearchView);

                mDestinationSearchView = (SearchView)mView.findViewById(R.id.destinationSearchView);

                mSourceSearchView.setQuery(mCurrentLocation, false);


                mBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(new ContextThemeWrapper(mContext, 
                        android.R.style.Theme_DeviceDefault_Dialog));

                mBuilder.setView(mView);

                mAlertDialog = mBuilder.create();

                mAlertDialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);

                mAlertDialog.setCancelable(false);
```

**My Question:** How to check if one searchview is focused and same for other.
I tried with this but it returns **null**

```
mAlertDialog.getWindow().getCurrentFocus().isFocused()
```

Comment: Check like this mSourceSearchView.isFocused();

Answer (score 0):

You can use `View.OnFocusChangeListener` :

```
mSourceSearchView.setOnFocusChangeListener(new OnFocusChangeListener() {

    @Override
    public void onFocusChange(View view, boolean hasFocus) {
        if(hasFocus){
            //do something
        }else{
            //something else
        }

    }
});
```

if you dont want to use the listener then you can use

```
mSourceSearchView.isFocused();
```

the [docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnFocusChangeListener.html). Hope it helps :)

Comment: it should work but don't know what is happening !!! its not even listening to the events callback.why??